# Invalid Configuration – yii\base\InvalidConfigException

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-user

I'm using xampp for windows 8 and i have recently installed `dektrium/yii2-user`.
I have followed the installation instructions here:

```
https://github.com/dektrium/yii2-user/blob/master/docs/installation.md
```

The changed part of my web.php looks now like this:

```
'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
            'class' => 'dektrium\user\Module',

        ],
```

I'm getting the error:

```
Missing required parameter "id" when instantiating "dektrium\user\Module".
```

And when I delete

```
    'class' => 'dektrium\user\Module',
```

the error disappears.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Most likely you inserted this line in the wrong section (`components`):

```
'components' => [
    'user' => [
        'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
        'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        // You inserted it here
    ],
],
```

But `yii2-user` is not component, it's module. Therefore you should include this in `modules` section of `config`.  It also mentioned in documentation:

```
'modules' => [
    'user' => [
        'class' => 'dektrium\user\Module',
    ],
],
```

Right after installation basic application does not have any modules so in that case you should create this section by yourself.